# Groovy Eclipse compiler plugin for maven. How compile files with "java" extension?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I want that Groovy Eclipse compiler compile files with 'java' extension. Now files with 'java' extension (in src/main/java) compile java compiler (more strict). Is tuning exist in "Groovy Eclipse Maven plugin" (https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin)
groovy compiler compile files with 'java' extension?

Comment: Use `groovyc` to compile both `.java` and `.groovy` files.

Comment: If you are asking for groovy-eclipse-compiler and groovy-eclipse-batch to compile both Groovy and Java sources, you are getting that.  The groovy-eclipse adapter routes Groovy sources to groovyc and Java sources to ecj (the Eclipse Compiler for Java aka JDT).

Comment: Thanks for answers! I am novice in Java and Maven. Please, can you say me how using  groovyc for certain Java sources?